# Simple Local Database Solution for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, database, csv, sequel, sequel-gem

I'm attempting to write a simple Ruby/Nokogiri scraper to get event information from multiple pages and then output it to a CSV that is attached to an email sent out weekly.

I have completed the scraping components and the CSV component and it's working perfectly. However, I now realize that I need to know when new events are added, which means I need some sort of database. Ideally I would just store this locally.

I've dabbled a bit with using the ruby gem 'sequel', but the data does not seem to persist beyond the running of the program. Do I need to download some database software to work with 'sequel'? Also I'm not using the Rails framework, just Ruby.

Any and all guidance is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Do you have an RDBMS installed on your resident machine to allow you to persist the data?

Comment: Before abandoning Sequel, you need to do more than "dabble". If the data isn't persisting, it's because you're using an in-memory SQLite database. While they're very useful for some tasks, a persisting database isn't usually one of them. Instead, look at using SQLite on disk, or PostgreSQL, MySQL or whatever else you have [that Sequel supports](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/index.html). It's extremely capable. http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Connecting+to+a+database describes how to use an on-disk SQLite DB.

Comment: You were absolutely right @the-Tin-Man. And that link is very helpful! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you did `Sequel.sqlite`, as in the first example in the Sequel README, which creates an in-memory SQLite database. To create a database in your filesystem instead of memory, just pass it a path, e.g.:

```
Sequel.sqlite("./my-database.db")
```

This is, of course, assuming that you have the sqlite3 gem installed. If the given file doesn't exist, it will be created.

This is [covered in the Sequel docs](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html).

Comment: Ah of course!! I was following the example from the Sequel README and didn't realize that when it said in-memory it would be destroyed once the program concluded running. Thanks very much @Jordan. I appreciate the help!